# How can I include json - libarys in Eclipse

Tags: json, include, eclipse-cdt

I am new to stackoverflow and hope you can help me with my problem.

I have downloaded some libraries from json(jsoncons, jsoncpp) and tried to get them running, but this does not work with eclipse.
it works if I create a nano file and then build it manually. pictures will show what I mean.

since I am relatively new to eclipse I need your help to find a solution here

thanks
yours Teddy

Eclipse

[image]

Nano

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that the indexer doesnt include the right paths, i had to   ifstream ifs("/home/teleskop/eclipse-workspace/json_include_test/test.json");